# Case command for checking two values

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Look at this code please:

```
char o,t; cin >> o >> t;
switch (o,t)
{
  case 's','g': cout << "Finish"; break;
  default: cout << "Nothing";
}
```

as you can see switch is set for two values, but in case command I can not check for both of them at the same time. What should I do? is there any way?

Comment: It seems you want to exit when "sg" is entered. If so, just input a string (char array), compare it with "sg" and exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do switch for two expressions at the same time. The switch part only compiles because there is a comma operator (which simply evaluates to the second value, in this case `t`).

Use plain old `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me ask another question. How can I copy those two char into a string value? for example string r; r=o+t; r should be "sg" but it will become another thing, do you know how to do it?

Comment: that invokes the addition operator for chars, it's like adding integers. `string("") + o + r` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

it's not proper syntax use instead

```
case 's':
case 'g':
 cout << "Finish"; break;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't `switch` on multiple values in C++.

```
switch (o,t)
```

uses the *comma operator* (it looks a lot like a pair would in some other languages, but it isn't).
The comma operator evaluates its left operand (`o`), ignores the value of that, and then returns the value of its right operand (`t`).
In other words, your `switch` only looks at `t`.
There is no way around this.

Your particular case is better written as

```
if (o == 's' && t == 'g')
{
    cout << "Finish";
}
else
{
    cout << "Nothing";
}
```

Comment: @Stranger: This really should be posted as another question, but I'll answer anyway: `char` is actually an integer type, so `o+t` adds two integers (and the result is the sum of the ASCII codes for the characters). You can however do `string r; r += o; r += t;` to get what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

```
char o,t; cin >> o >> t;
switch (o,t)
{
  case 's':
  case 'g': cout << "Finish"; break;
  default: cout << "Nothing";
}
```

In switch when matched case is found, all operator after that are executed. That's why you should write `break;` operator after `case`-es to exit switch. So if you want to do the same in several cases you should just put them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error, the correct code is

```
char o,t; cin >> o >> t;
switch (o)
{
  case 's':case 'g': cout << "Finish"; break;
  default: cout << "Nothing";
}

switch (t)
{
  case 's':case 'g': cout << "Finish"; break;
  default: cout << "Nothing";
}
```