# What does comma operator mean in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, c

I was given a question and was asked to give the output.

```
int main(void){  
    int x = 2;  
    switch(x){  
        case 1,2,1: printf("Case 1 is executed");  
            break;  
        case 2,3,1: printf("Case 2 is executed");  
            break;  
        default : printf("Default case us executed");  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

The above code gives output as "Case 1 is executed" in Turbo C, But on codeblocks and compile online, it gives a compiler error.

Which one is correct? Is it a compiler error or not? And if not, why does the code run only on Turbo C?

Comment: That looks bizarre. I have a hunch turbo C is probably evaluating those cases first [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: @RageD That wouldn't explain it either: both `1,2,1` and `2,3,1` ordinarily evaluate to the same value, so I would *still* expect Turbo C to give a compiler error if that is the reason.

Comment: @hvd Good point-- in any event, it's still ambiguous. Even in the answers below, it should not be allowed since case enumeration would still provide duplicates.

Comment: My compiler is doing exactly what RageD stated.  It evaluates only the 1 in 1,2,1 and then complains that it didn't see a colon (:) after that number.

Comment: Testing with Turbo C++ 3.0 shows that it gives a compiler error: http://imgur.com/KsIy2ja

Comment: Turbo C++ 1.01 and the even earlier Turbo C 2.0 also show compiler errors, and they properly diagnose the expressions as non-constant. So... "The above code gives output as "Case 1 is executed" in Turbo C,"? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Some related links: 1) [Verify 4: Using Comma operator in side switch case](http://www.c4learn.com/how-to-use-comma-operator-in-different-program-statements.html), 2)  [Case command for checking two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358224/case-command-for-checking-two-values), 3) [Comma operator in constant-expression](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/tXL0RNFSlK4)

Comment: Code::Blocks isn't compiler but an environment. If you want to describe that the compiler used by Code::Blocks doesn't accept the code then it's worth to name the compiler (and version).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> is it a compiler error or not.

The code is invalid in both languages: the `case` expression must be a constant expression, and a constant expression can't contain a comma operator. (In C, this is stated explicitly; in C++, you have to unpick the grammar to find that a *constant-expression* must be a *conditional-expression*, which can't contain a comma).

Even if you were allowed to use the comma operator here, the `switch` statement would still be invalid since two cases would both have the same value, 1.

> And if not why does the code run only on turbo C.

Because both languages have changed significantly since that prehistoric compiler was last updated. Don't use it if you want to learn variants of C or C++ from this century.

Comment: Agree with @Mike - If you are using Code::Blocks, minGW is a well maintained, open source compiler available for no charge.  It would be a better choice than Turbo C.

Comment: The only variant of C form this century is C11. Not all "modern" compilers even support C99.

Comment: To quote [a comment on another turbo-c question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289354/output-difference-in-gcc-and-turbo-c#comment3405571_3289354): *Take the hint, use gcc*.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sorry, I keep forgetting not to be sarcastic when the question is tagged "C".

Comment: Compilers are allowed to implement extensions that don't affect conforming programs, and every compiler does; so the fact that Turbo C allows this shouldn't be considered a slight on Turbo C

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No, but the fact that Turbo C knows nothing about the last two major revisions of both C and C++ might be considered a slight, if you want to use a modern language. If you're only interested in 1990-vintage code, then it's probably fine, but I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Well, "can't contain a comma" is a bit too strong of a statement. The grammar allows for a comma in a *conditional-expression* as long as you descend all the way to the *primary-expression*. Which means that you can sneak a comma in as long as the whole thing is parenthesized. The explicit prohibition to use comma in constant expressions was there in C++03 [expr.const], but is gone in C++11. So `case (1,2,1):` is fine in C++11 (but not in C++03 or C). The original format is, of course, invalid.

Answer (score 10):

*What does comma operator mean in a switch statement?*
It means you have an old compiler.

***Edit*** post (to show `case range` example)

The first two examples (including your original code ) exhibit incorrect switch statement syntax (with explanations).  The third code example shows how stacking case labels is done correctly:

In your code, the compiler should have flagged the first comma after  `case 1,`<-- here

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void){  
    int x = 2;  
    switch(x)
    {  
        case 1,2,1: printf("Case 1 is executed");  
        break;  //error flagged at first comma, and all comma after in case
        case 2,3,1: printf("Case 2 is executed");  
        break;  
        default : printf("Default case is executed");  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

And, even modified like this you should also get a duplicate label error:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void){  
    int x = 2;  
    switch(x)
    {  
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 1: printf("Case 1 is executed"); //duplicate label 1 error. (and others below) 
            break;  
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 1: printf("Case 2 is executed");  
            break;

        default : printf("Default case is executed");  
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

This example is perfectly legal *(C99, C11)* and useful:  i.e., there are no duplicate labels, and the syntax complies with correct switch usage by stacking *unique* labels to handle conditions where `case 1: OR case 2: OR case 3:` should be handled the same way, (in the same block). And of course the same is true for cases 4, 5 and 6.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void){  
    int x = 2;  
    switch(x)
    {  
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: printf("Case 1,2 or 3 is executed"); //duplicate label 1 error. (and others below) 
            break;  
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: printf("Case 4,5 or 6 is executed");  
            break;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;  
}
```

This last example is included just for completeness.  It illustrates the `case range` expression.   Although gaining interest among C programmers, it is not yet part of C99 or C11,  rather an extension of  [Sun (a flavor of unix)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7598/giphi/index.html) and  [GNU C compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges)  *(et al)*:

```
...
    switch(x)
    {  
            case 'a' ... 'z':  //note: spaces between all characters ('a') and ellipses are required
                    printf("lowercase alpha char detected");
                    break;
            case 'A' ... 'B':
                    printf("uppercase alpha char detected");
                    break;

            default: printf("Default case is executed");  
    }
...
```

The reason for the ambiguous results you are seeing from one compiler to another may be that Turbo C is really *really* old.  The version you are using was likely implemented against a version of the C standards that is no longer current.

Consider changing to a current compiler.  An inexpensive (free) alternative is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).  MinGW is a very well maintained, open source compiler.  If you like using Integrated Development Environments (IDE), [Code::Blocks](http://www.cprogramming.com/code_blocks/) is one option, also free, and as an option comes bundled with MinGW.

Regarding compatibility, search for [Comparison to Other Compiler Suites](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw) in this link to read about MinGW extensions.  MinGW extensions, while expanding capabilities, sometimes make code written using them non-portable with other *current* compilers.  Recommend using caution when using them.

Answer (score 1):

Turbo C uses comma operator on switch cases and takes the last value, for example case 1, 2, 3: will be compiled as case 3: case 2, 3, 1 as case 1: hence Turbo C will not give you any error. Where as other compilers will not allow you case 1, 2, 3: kind of statement itself.

But in your case even Turbo c will give error because case statements are something like this
case 1, 2, 1: and case 3, 2, 1: which will be complied as case 1: and case 1: hence as per switch case rules you can have only 1 case with a value and you cannot repeat the case

I prefer to use gcc compiler rather Turbo C

Answer (score 0):

> is it a compiler error or not.

It will cause a compilation error (don't know about **TURBO C++** but in modern compilers).
This is not the way switch statement works (invalid syntax in c/c++). You cannot reuse a `case` value in `switch` statement (see the [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eb85b7ad3bcc2c4) given by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris))  The way you can do this;

```
 switch(x){
            case 1: case 2: case 3: printf("Case 1 is executed");
            break;
            default : printf("Default case us execyted"); 
          }
```

Comment: @chris; Oops! I forgot about that.

Comment: @haccks But still you don't answer the question.

Comment: @haccks - I am not one of the downvoters, but can you see that your statement `It is not a compiler error but it will cause a compilation error` could be confusing to a person not yet familiar with debugging lingo?  Just offering a possible _why_

Comment: @ryyker; :). Ya. I am realizing now. I am thinking it is better to remove that line.

Comment: @downvoter; It is a very bad practice not to remove downvote after answer being edited (corrected).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use twice the same 'case' value
This is not correct: `case 1: case 2: case 1: printf("Case 1 is executed");`
Tried to compile on VS2010 => (error C2196: case value '1' already used)

Comment: No, you can't, but that's not relevant. The code in the question is `case 1, 2, 1:` (which is illegal because comma operators are not allowed in that context), not `case 1: case 2: case 1:`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, today one may use the [GCC case ranges extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466896/what-does-comma-operator-mean-in-a-switch-statement) when it is appropriate (which is not often) for similar results (only ranges are supported, not arbitrary lists of values).

```
case 1 ... 5:
case 'A' ... 'Z':
```